# Как вывести список подзадач эпиков, зная только номер релиза, к которому привязаны эпики?

Tags: jira

В нашем проекте есть главная сущность "Релиз", с ним могут быть связаны сущности с типом "эпик", а внутри сущности "эпик" могут быть подзадачи с типом "Задача". Мне бы хотелось сформировать запрос, который будет выводить все подзадачи, связанные с эпиками определенного релиза (не перечисляю в запросе список эпиков)

Comment: релиз это `fixVersion` ? или какое-то отдельное поле?

Comment: Релиз - это сущность с типом "Release"